# Swipe back gesture on iOS is overwritten by WillPopScope

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If I am using WillPopScope to overwrite the BackButton behavior with a new route, it works fine. But on iOS, the automatic 'SwipeBack' gesture is not working any more. How can I set the SwipeBack gesture on iOS to push the current screen to the page with the class 'StartScreen'?

```
WillPopScope(onWillPop: (){
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => StartScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Is BuckButton behavior that you say on AppBar or system’s back button of bottom?

Comment: This is being debated [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203) and that's an expected behavior so far.

Comment: But how can I overwrite the swipe back gesture of iOS with a different one of my choice?

Answer (score 3):

`WillPopScope` is not meant to affect navigation (I.e.: push a route on the navigator). It is meant for vetoing (preventing) navigation away from the current route when you don't want the user to navigate away. (For example, when it might result in data loss.)

Try [CupertinoWillPopScope](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_will_pop_scope), as it allows you to conditionally veto the back navigation. So you can only block it when there's an actual need.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a very late answer, but at the moment there is no clear opportunity to listen to this gesture

You can achieve the call to onWillPop when you press the back button, and at the same time do not block the gesture if you make a descendant class of the ModalRoute class (or its descendants, such as MaterialPageRoute) and override the **hasScopedWillPopCallback** method (however, the gesture will not call onWillPop)